# JQuery - SlideToggle all but not - collapse other categories (FAQ/Q&A Section)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an FAQ section which uses JQuery .slideToggle to display the answers, see the JSFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/hq1z63cz/

```
$("[class^='panel-heading']").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();       
});
```

I'd like it if when clicking on a question, all answers collapse except for the one corresponding with the clicked question.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of jQuery's [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method to affect all others except the current panel.

```
$("[class^='panel-heading']").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle()
        .parent().siblings().find('.panel-collapse').slideUp(); 

});
```

Comment: yep that'll suffice. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

to whom it may concern: using JQuery is unnecessary. It's come to my attention that there's a bootstrap UI for this accordion that comes out of the box found here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/accordion